# vb.net converting string to date format

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert string into date on vb, but for some reason I get the following error message.

```
System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

I am getting the date from date control on winform

```
dim selectedDate as string = dateControl1.text
dim selectedDt as Date = Date.Parse(selectedDate)
```

but if I put the same value in code instead of getting from dateControl, is ok

```
dim selectedDate as string = "19/01/2021"
dim selectedDt as Date = Date.Parse(selectedDate)
```

so I try to see if there is any different between value from dateControl1 and when type in the code since dateControl1.text should  returning the same string value so I try to do this

```
dim selectedDate as string = "19/01/2021"
if selectedDate = dateControl1.text then
  debug.print ("same")
else
  debug.print ("different")
end if
```

when I run it, debug print "same"

and if I do this

```
dim selectedDate as string = "19/01/2021"
if selectedDate = dateControl1.text then
  debug.print ("same")
else
  debug.print ("different")
end if

dim selectedDt as Date = Date.Parse(dateControl1.text)
```

I get the same error even though the debug say "same"

so I am really confuse, why date.parse show error when I am getting the value from dateControl1.text and it's exactly the same string

am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Regards

- Haris -

Comment: What is the date/time format of the current CultureInfo? Try `DateTime.TryParse()`, providing the parsing format. What is a *date control* (a control provided by what platform)? Doesn't it provide a `Value` property that returns a Date object?

Comment: You are likely on a system where the standard date format is "MM/dd/yyyy" and you are passing value that can only be interpreted as "dd/MM/yyyy". You would need to use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` and specify the exact format or else call `Parse` or `TryParse` and provide an IFormatProvider that provided the appropriate date format. As suggested though, if you're using WinForms and a `DateTimePicker` control then you should not be touching its `Text` property but, rather, using the `Value` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, it should work:

```
dim selectedDt as Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateControl1.text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

For a safer way, you have to double check your value of the textbox first. by a `try`

[DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

What control is the date control? If it's a DateTimePicker then you can just get the date using the .Value property without having to do any conversion.

```
dim selectedDt as Date = dateControl1.Value
```